# Laravel - How to list new articles under events

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an application under laravel, when a user adds an article, I launch an event. I recover well this event on the front via vuejs. My problem being how to display the new record each time?

Comment: "I recover well this event on the front via vuejs" what do you recover ? any precise data like `id`? how ? These points should be included in your question.

Comment: I get the whole article (ID / Name / Slug) etc. What I can not do is to list all the articles and "refresh" the component when an event happens

Answer (score 0):

You should use websockets.

Read more about it here https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/broadcasting